# Read data from subscribe

Tags: angular, get

Why I can not read value of subscribe in Typescript angular 5.
Error on debug with chrome: message:"Unexpected end of input".

My code:

```
  customer: ICustomer[] = [];
  errorMessage: string;

 constructor(private getCustomerService: GetCustomerService) {

    }
  ngOnInit(): void {
        const param = this.getCustomerService.getCustomer().subscribe(customer => { this.customer = customer },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
    }
```

The Service:

```
  getCustomer(): Observable<ICustomer[]> {

    let UserId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CurrentUser"));

    return this._http.get<ICustomer[]>(this.ORIGIN_URL + UserId).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError))

  }
```

I can read the data only in the HTML file:

```
[(ngModel)]="customer.email"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be already a JSON, do not use JSON.stringify

```
  tap(data => console.log('All:', data)),
```

Comment: If I remove JSON.stringify the error is :"data is not defined", and the console: All: [object Object]! but I can not understand how the html read the data from where if I have this error?